# Solr DIH and SAXParseException Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: xml, solr, dih

I'm new to Solr and trying to index the file system, using Solr's DIH. Funny thing is, it worked just fine - for a little while. Now the DIH won't initialize and I keep getting a SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Any ideas?
I'm using Solr 3.6.0 on Debian. And I checked the config file with a hex editor but found nothing.

Here's the data-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" name="bin"/>
<document>      
    <entity name="files"
        processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
        fileName=".*.(pdf)|(doc)|(docx)|(ppt)|(pptx)"
        baseDir="/mnt/C"
        rootEntity="false"
        dataSource="null"
        recursive="true"
        onError="skip">
        <field name="id" column="fileAbsolutePath"/>
        <field name="lastModified" column="fileLastModified"/>
        <entity name="f"
            processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
            url="${files.fileAbsolutePath}"
            dataSource="bin"
            format="text"
            onError="skip">
            <field name="fileName" column="file"/>
            <field name="author" column="Author" meta="true"/>
            <field name="title" column="title" meta="true"/>
            <field name="text" column="text"/>
        </entity>
    </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

And the error:

```
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Exception occurred while initializing context
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.loadDataConfig(DataImporter.java:231)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.<init>(DataImporter.java:119)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBody(DataImportHandler.java:168)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:391)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1404)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1014)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:819)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:748)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:239)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:288)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.loadDataConfig(DataImporter.java:216)
... 18 more
```

Comment: it looks like incorrect xml config. use some service for testing it - http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html

Comment: I do not see the `</dataConfig>` at the end of your data-config.xml ...

Comment: I don't know why it didn't appear in my post above, but </dataConfig> is there in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The XML validates for me. And the error points at line 1, character 1. Sometimes it could be the [Byte-Order-mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) issue, which is an invisible character right at the file start.

Perhaps you edited the file in some editor that got too excited and added BOM explicitly. Re-check the first 1-2 characters in hex editor. Or try just copying this content into a very plain text editor and seeing if that would work.

Comment: According to ghex there is no BOM. Copying the content didn't help either. I even re-typed the whole thing in Notepad++, but the error still persists. If it's not BOM, what else could it be?

Comment: Is it possible that there are two files and you are looking at the wrong one? Can you put an example DIH file instead and see if it is read in the admin UI.

Comment: Looks like you have some issues with relative path then. Or permissions. If you are on Windows, try using something like [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and see where it is actually looking for that file. On Linux, you can use trace/strace/truss/dtrace (different system - different utilities) for the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and sorry for the late response. I'm afraid I haven't made any progress with this problem at all, it doesn't seem to be relative path or permissions